# How to change date format in the webform date element?

Tags: 8, webforms, datetime

I have added a date element to my webform.

Now I want to change the date format for the date element.

I have used the following code.

```
function my_module_webform_element_alter(array &$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, array $context) {
  if ($element['#type'] === 'date') {
    $element['#date_date_format'] = 'd/m/Y';
  }
}
```

But I can still see the date element like this.

[image]

And when I try to submit the form and I get an error on date field.

Also is there a way to change the date format in the email which webform sends?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using Webform 6.x/

For Drupal 9.x, you need to install the [jQueryUI datepicker module](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_ui_datepicker) and then enable the datepicker via the UI.

For Drupal 8.x, the jQueryUI datepicker is included.

Comment: I am using Webform 5.x.

Comment: Did you enable the date picker?

Answer (score 0):

The date format in the field depends on the operating system settings. So it will display the date format according to the format set in your OS.

For the date format in the email, You need to change it from `admin/structure/webform/config/elements` in the `Element formats` section by setting the default format for the date field.